# R: Converting numeric timestamp to POSIXct object returns NA

Tags: r, posixct

I know this is a common problem, but none of the many other questions I saw fixed this for me. I'm trying to convert numeric timestamps to POSIXct, but no matter what I do, it gives me NA. For example:

```
as.POSIXct(20090319043255, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S", origin="1970-01-01")
```

I've tried just about every variation on the formatting I can think of: inserting spaces, changing the origin format, excluding the origin (which just gives me the "origin must be supplied" error), everything. I'm stumped. Is there something stupid I'm missing?

Before you ask, yes, I've checked the locale. I'm in the United States.

Comment: The input needs to be a string. `as.POSIXct(as.character(20090319043255), format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` works.

Comment: Why do numeric objects not work in this case? I don't know the reasoning behind that.

Comment: With a numeric value, it is interpreted as *a numeric time as the number of seconds since an epoch*,  And you don't need the `format` parameter in this case, however, I don't believe that gives you correct output as your value is obviously a string with formats.

Comment: Psidom is exactly right. If you want as.POSIXct to work correctly with a numeric argument you'll have to use the number of seconds since origin. Try this for example: `as.POSIXct(1238000000, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: I think I understand. So if I present the as.POSIXct command with a numeric object, R assumes I'm asking for the amount of time passed since the origin, but if I give it a character object, it assumes I want it coerced to a POSIXct object. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You can see ?as.POSIXct for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the lubridate package.
Try running the below code.

```
> library(lubridate)
> ymd_hms("20090319043255")
[1] "2009-03-19 04:32:55 UTC"
```